# mouse down and take a screenshot of an element

Tags: puppeteer, jest-puppeteer, jest-image-snapshot

I am trying to simulate a mousedown action on an element then take a snapshot but this doesn't seem to work as the screenshot isn't what I expect.

according to the api docs, this is what it does

```
mouse.down([options])
options <Object>
button <"left"|"right"|"middle"> Defaults to left.
clickCount <number> defaults to 1. See UIEvent.detail.
returns: <Promise>
Dispatches a mousedown event.
```

I have tried the following:

```
  it('primary button visually looks correct on mouse down', async () => {
    await page.goto('my_url_page');
    await page.waitForSelector(testData.button, 20000);
    const elementHandle = await page.$(testData.button);
    await page.mouse.move(0, 0);
    await page.mouse.down();
    const image = await elementHandle.screenshot();

    expect(image).toMatchImageSnapshot();
  });
```

the button has some animation when the mouse is pressed down and this is what I want to take a screenshot of.

Appreciate the support with this

Comment: You are moving the mouse to the position `(0, 0)`. Is the element actually at that position? Also, it would be easier to help you if you could provide one of the images.

Comment: hi, yes the image is exactly at that position..```<button class="sc-iwsKbI mKOSa" data-test="" type="submit">Primary Button</button>```

Comment: And is the clickable part of the button also in that position? The button could have a rounded corner, a `margin` or something similar making the corner of the button not clickable.

Comment: Hi again, just to confirm, the click works fine. It’s the mouse down action I’m struggling with. How to call mouse down on an element i.e the button.